# Можно ли обойтись без "в частности"?

Tags: вводные-слова, как

> Угрозы безопасности, такие как международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм, приобретают все более угрожающий характер.

"Международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм" - это обособленные однородные члены в обороте, начинающемся со слов "такие как"?

Если в начале этого оборота будет вводное (скажем, в частности), то так ли надо будет расставить запятые:

Угрозы безопасности, в частности такие как международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм, приобретают все более угрожающий характер.

Или "в частности" будет избыточным?

> Агрессоры не остановятся перед применением средств массового уничтожения, таких, как атомное и водородное оружие.

Здесь после "таких" нужна запятая, а если нужна, то на основании чего?

Answer (score 2):

1) **Вводное слово используется**

Угрозы безопасности, **в частности такие как международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм,** приобретают все более **напряженный** характер.

Наличие слова ***в частности*** связано с текстом. Если речь идет об общей картине безопасного существования, то международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм ― это **частный** вид угроз. Если выделены только две основные угрозы и другие варианты не учитываются, то возможен вариант без вводного слова.

Примечание. Повтор: **угрозы, угрожающий**.

В данном случае, как я думаю, ***в частности*** не помешает. Вводное слово стоит вначале обособленного оборота и не отделяется от него запятой.

2) **Без вводного слова (варианты оформления)**

(1) Угрозы безопасности,  **такие как международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм**, приобретают все более напряженный  характер.

(2) **Такие** угрозы безопасности, **как международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм,** приобретают все более напряженный характер.

Повтор: **угрозы, угрожающий**.

Comment: "Если речь идет об общей картине безопасного существования, то международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм ― это частный вид угроз" => OK.  Напишем: "Угрозы безопасности, в частности международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм". Слова "такие как" — лишние.

Comment: Это группа особо опасных угроз, возможно, она обозначена не полностью.

Comment: Не слишком ли сложное нагромождение? Угрозы безопасности, в частности групппа угроз, представителями которой являются международный терроризм и религиозный экстремизм. И вы верите, что именно это автор хотел сказать?

Comment: Автор хотел привести пример, выбрав из всех угроз наиболее важные. Совсем не плохо, если он обозначил его как частный пример. Напряженный характер приобретают весь спектр угроз, а не только эти две позиции. Поэтому это именно частный пример, так что всё на месте.

Comment: Чтобы привести пример, не нужно строить двухуровневые логическое конструкции такого вида: вот вам, например, одна из групп угроз, а в ней, например, международный терроризм и религиозный  экстремизм.

Comment: Хорошо, хорошо, не нужно, не будем ничего строить.  Но все-таки мне хотелось бы вас предупредить о том, что вы видите двухуровневые логические конструкции в предложении, построенном по самым стандартным меркам и никакого глубокого смысла не имеющем.

Comment: А если так (никакого глубокого смысла не имеющем), то слова, ничего не добавляющие к смыслу сказанного, желательно выбросить.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь два вопроса (в будущем, пожалуйста, задавайте каждый вопрос отдельно).

1. "В частности" и "такие как" в данном случае синонимичны, не ставьте их рядом.
2. После слова *таких* запятая не нужна:

**Агрессоры не остановятся перед применением средств массового уничтожения, таких как атомное и водородное оружие.**

[ТАКОЙ (,) КАК, местоимение + союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722):

> Однако в некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»:
>   2) если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не требуется): Туристы посетили старинные города, такие как Суздаль, Владимир, Ростов Великий.